# Try...catch is returning token "u" (probably from undefined). Can't see where I'm failing in writing the async operation

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, networking, request

I'm learning javascript and php for web development using wordpress.

I've intentionally caused an error with a filter in wordpress function, but the error is not being caught by the try..catch block. Instead, I get the following in the console:

'SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0'

Here is the javascript code:

```
  async createNote(){
    let note = this.getNote();

    let data = {
        title: note.title.value,
        content: note.body.value,
        status: 'publish',
    }

    this.createInit.body = JSON.stringify(data);

    try {
        let response = await fetch(`${wordpressData.rootUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/note/`, this.createInit);
        let newPostData = await response.json();

        note.title.value = '';
        note.body.value = '';

        this.myNotes.insertAdjacentHTML(
            'afterbegin',
            `<li note-id="${newPostData.id}" class="fade-in-calc">
            <input readonly class="note-title-field" value="${newPostData.title.raw}">
            <span class="edit-note"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</span>
            <span class="delete-note"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete</span>
            <textarea readonly class="note-body-field">${newPostData.content.raw}</textarea>
            <span class="update-note btn btn--blue btn--small"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Save</span>
        </li>`
        );

        //note animation

        let finalHeight;
        let newPostHTMLBlock = document.querySelector('#my-notes li');

        setTimeout(() => {
            finalHeight = `${newPostHTMLBlock.offsetHeight}px`;
            newPostHTMLBlock.style.height = '0px';
        }, 30);

        setTimeout(() => {
            newPostHTMLBlock.classList.remove('fade-in-calc');
            newPostHTMLBlock.style.height = finalHeight;
        }, 50);

        setTimeout(() => {
            newPostHTMLBlock.style.removeProperty('height');
        }, 450);

    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

And here is the php function that generates the error:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'university_filter_notes', 10, 2);

function university_filter_notes($data, $postInfo){
    if($data['post_type'] != 'note') return $data;  //escape condition

    if(count_user_posts(get_current_user_id(), 'note') > 4 AND !$postInfo['ID']) {
        die("User has reached note post type limit."); //this gets called correctly, but I don't think it's passing the message.
    }

    $data['post_content'] = sanitize_textarea_field($data['post_content']);
    $data['post_title'] = sanitize_text_field($data['post_title']);

    if($data['post_status'] != 'trash'){
        $data['post_status'] = 'private';
    }

    return $data;
}
```

When I add `console.log(response)` inbetween the fetch and parse requests, it returns the following when the error is **not** triggered

[image: log when the function runs]

When the error is triggered from the php filter function, the following response is returned:

[image: log when the error happens]

EDIT: I think the problem is not knowing where the message from php "die" goes inside the response object.

Comment: Check what `response` is before you call `response.json()`

Comment: Seems to be a standard `promise` object, with the properties `body`, `headers` and so forth.

I've checked by logging the object itself right after fetching the promise. However, the logging only runs when the error is not triggered. (The error triggers when the user has reached a post limit)

Comment: The question is what *the content* is. My assumption is that it's `undefined` and parsing it as JSON fails.

Comment: Add `console.log(response)` right between the fetch and `newPostData` and tell us what it returns

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I didn't make it clear enough in the opening question.
I have a php filter function that runs whenever a post request is sent to the data base.

This filter checks for two things: the `post_type`, which in this case is `'note'`, and a wordpress function that counts the specific post types and compares it to a limit. When both conditions evaluate to true, the filter returns the request with an error.

When the limit is not reached, the function is working fine. The response object is being parsed and the HTML outputs. However, when the error happens, it is not caught.

Comment: What would be the best way to share what the 'response' object returns?

Comment: What does the console log mentioned above return when you run it with the error? Please add it in the the question by clicking the `Edit` link on the bottom

Comment: I've added an image showing the object in the console.

Comment: So is the error in your php backend?

Comment: Yes, the error is in the php backend. Afaik, the response should be returned with the error message coded in the backend. Would you like to see the wordpress error function as well?

Comment: I think I had tried to insert the logging after the parsing before. The response is being returned with the error now. It just doesn't get parsed. I've added another image showing the object returned when the error happens.